# how should be named a folder where all of functionality operating with data from db and and modifying that data with ORM is stored?

Tags: database

How should I call a folder where I store all functionality operating with data from db and where I modify db data through ORM?

examples of functions:

```
@database_sync_to_async
def add_superuser(user_id):
    new_superuser = Superuser.objects.create(external_id=user_id)
    new_superuser.save()

@database_sync_to_async
def get_on_mode_report(group_id, mode, specified_date: datetime=None) -> Type[ReportParameters]:
    journal = Journal.objects.get(external_id=group_id)

    match mode:
       case ReportMode.TODAY:
           date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
           corresponding_report = ReportParameters.objects.get(date=date, journal=journal)

       case ReportMode.LAST:
           journal_reports = ReportParameters.objects.filter(journal=journal)
           corresponding_report = journal_reports.order_by('date')[len(journal_reports) - 1] # bare -1 is not supported

       case ReportMode.ON_DATE:
           corresponding_report = ReportParameters.objects.get(date=specified_date, journal=journal)

    return corresponding_report
```